# Possible to retrieve an authorization code using broker assisted logins and ADAL?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, office365, adal

Is it possible to retrieve an authorization code (not token) using the ADAL library for iOS & Android, while also supporting broker assisted logins?

From what I can tell, all of the following are true:

1. Broker assisted logins are only supported in ADAL 1.0
2. ADAL 1.0 only has APIs for retrieving access and refresh tokens. There are no APIs for retrieving an authorization code
3. ADAL 2.0 does *not* support broker assisted logins
4. ADAL 2.0 supports retrieving an authorization code

Ideally, I’d like to use ADAL with broker assisted login in my app to retrieve an authorization code which I’ll then send to my back-end to store. The back-end will be responsible for generating access/refresh tokens using the code and a secret, as well as all communication between my app and the Office 365 API.

It doesn’t seem like this is possible though, because there isn’t a variant of the ADAL lib that supports both broker assisted login and auth codes.

Is what I described here accurate, or is there a way to use authorization codes + broker assisted logins with ADAL?

Comment: What's an access code in this context? Do you perhaps mean 'authorization code'?

Comment: AFAIK, MSAL does support brokers, at least the iOS one.

Comment: @Marc Yes, that should have read authorization code, not access code. I updated the original post. We need feature parity across iOS and Android which is why MSAL is not an option today (MSAL preview is only available on iOS AFAIK)